# Date format in Combo box

Tags: vba, excel

Actually I am writing a code for highlight or delete the rows where column "A" has > the date selected in combo box. I am using below codes

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Application.EnableEvents = False
ComboBox1.Value = Format(ComboBox1.Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

ComboBox2.Value = Format(ComboBox2.Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")

End Sub

Private Sub okButton_Click()

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 6724
    If Range("A" & i).Value > ComboBox1.Value Then
        With Selection.Interior
           .ColorIndex = 34
           .Pattern = xlSolid
        End With
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

When I execute this nothing happens.
Then print combo box value in cell so that I can find out the place where the problem is, and I found that the date format in combo box & print date is different in format. 
there may be other issue with my code & enable event= false is also not working. any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try: `If Range("A" & i).Value2 > fix(ComboBox1.Value) Then`

Answer (score 0):

I'm on an iPad now and can't check what I propose, but the way I would tackle this problem is to ensure that column A has a date in it, a value like 41234, and never mind how that cell is formatted.
You can convert any date in Combobox1 using CDate(Combobox1.Value). Bear in mind that CDate requires a valid date in string format. The result of the CDate function is a Long, which is comparable with the date value in your column A. You should be able to use your existing code to act on it.